# codeigniter inherints controller from controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have Admin.php as contrller for dashboard,signin and logout
but in my application 
the admin user can edit news or add news I wanna separate news & admin controller and news controller work under admin 

to understand my I wanna URL like http://localhost/nkmf/admin/

after admin if I write **news** get my news dashboard

and the URL be Like: http://localhost/nkmf/admin/news/

and after news if I enter 
**editeNews** open editing form for selected news

and URL be like http://localhost/nkmf/admin/news/editNews?id=

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create sub folders named admin,news in controller folder

move your admin.php controller to the new subfolder named admin.

so you can access it by

http://localhost/appname/admin/controller_name/function_name

Comment: OK  but already admin is controller the subfolder and controller have a same name

Comment: you can rename the controller to admin_controller if you want .just make sure you change the class name too.  you can access it by http://localhost/app_name/admin/admin_controller

Answer (score 0):

As far as I have understood from your question the way you can achieve this is by either creating or overriding the **.htaccess file** or **routes** method. In which define your required url which leads to the the particular filename.php file. But for this you must know how to access and define the **.htacess** file or the **routes** class. If you are capable of handling htaccess file with regex, then you got it

Remember the codeIgniter url structure is  **http(s)://domain_name/sub_division/controller_name/function_name/parameter**